# Проблема с манифест файлом IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Присоединил в проекте jar JAX-RS скачанный с манифест файлом..

При попытке использования Response class я получаю ошибку , javax.ws.rs.core is not imported in the manifest?

Открыл сам манифест вроде всё нормально.. Я новичёк в IDEA.. Что тут нехватает в моём случаи?

Перешол с эклипса, там вообше с такими проблемами не сталкивался.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А чем не устроило добавление библиотек через `Project Structure`?
`File -> Project Structure -> пункт Libraries`. Жмешь плюс, выбираешь `Java`, указываешь путь, жмешь `Apply` и готово. Библиотека должна появиться в пункте `External libraries`

Comment: Поменял ! Сделанно как ты сказал.. Тоже самое происходит!

Comment: есть ссылка на правельное подсоединение библиотек в IDEA ?

Comment: Ну ранее просто такой ошибки не возникало. Могу посоветовать попробовать импортировать зависимости через мавен или же по новой создать весь проект

Comment: Maven решил проблему

Comment: Ну отлично. Мавен все таки лучше справляется с импортом. А по поводу самой ошибки - она не в манифесте джарника, а вроде как в каком-то конфиг файлике идеи.